# Laravel Unit Test - POST Request Payload

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I need help in creating a unit test case for Laravel. It's an API end point accepting a json as the POST payload (NOT POST form) and basically just creating an entry in the database based on that json object. The API works fine but I'm having trouble in creating the unit test.

The controller code contains

```
$request = Request::instance();
$content = $request->getContent();
$inputRequest = json_decode($content);
```

I don't know how to pass the payload into the unit test code (extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`)

Anyone able to help?

Thanks heaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when using [call()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.html#method_call%20%20%E2%80%9Cabc%E2%80%9D) method provided by laravel in a unit test.

the sixth parameter $content(String) can be used to pass in the post payload in test case class:

```
$this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $files, $server, jsonencode($yourdata), $changeHistory);
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, it works. I think you meant `json_encode` instead of `jsonencode`. If I don't really set $files and $server, however, is there a more elegant way of calling the function rather than passing empty arrays for those two, just to get to the `$content`? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When using the alternative [action()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.html#method_action) method, make sure you add an extra array after `$uri`, the signature is a bit different, it has the `$wildcards` array:

```php
Response::action(
    string $method, 
    string $action, 
    array $wildcards = array(), 
    array $parameters = array(), 
    array $files = array(), 
    array $server = array(), 
    string $content = null, 
    bool $changeHistory = true
)
```